# I want to make program in C printing each number of full number

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[1000];
    int i = 0;
    scanf("%s", &a);
    while (a[i] != 0) {
        printf("%c\n", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

"A large integer of up to 1,000 digits is given as input. Write a program that prints out each digit of the integer after receiving the corresponding integer." was the problem and I don't know what is not complete in my code. I got 4/5 point. answer have to be like:

Input: `+456`

Output:

```
+
4
5
6
```

Comment: minimum change: `scanf("%s", a);` (remove `&`)

Comment: You need an array if size 1001 to hold a string of 1000 digits plus a terminating thanks byte.  You should present overflow using `”%1000s”` too, and remove the `&`.

Comment: Hint: `putchar ('\n');` instead of `printf ("\n");` -- there is no conversion needed in the *format string*, so there is no need to call the variadic `printf` function. Simply use `putchar()` to output a single character to `stdout` or `fputc()` to output a single character to a file.

Comment: @나가을: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two issues:

#### 1.

```
scanf("%s", &a);
```

The argument `a` already decays to a pointer to the first element of array `a` -> so the type of it as argument is actually `char *`. Thus, `&a` is of type `char (*)[1000]`.

There is a type mismatch to the expected argument of type `char *` for the `%s` conversion specifier.

If you use GCC as compiler, the `-Wall` option (or respectively `-Wformat=`) had showed you a warning about this:

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[1000]' [-Wformat=]

    9 |     scanf("%s",&a);
      |            ~^  ~~
      |             |  |
      |             |  char (*)[1000]
      |             char *
```

---

#### 2.

Furthermore, if you need to store an integral number **up** to 1000 digits - which includes the case of a 1000 digit integer, you forgot that you need one element more to store the string-terminating null character (`'\0'`):

```
char a[1001];
```

Else, if the user inputs a number of 1000 digits, the null character would be stored beyond the bounds of the array, which invokes undefined behavior.

---

Additionally:

Use a length modifer to ensure there will occur no buffer overflow if the user attempts to enter a number of more than 1000 digits:

```
scanf("%1000s", a);
```

or use `fgets()` which is ensures this by default as it requires the number of characters to be written as second argument.

```
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
```

`sizeof(a)` is appropriate as `sizeof(char)` is always `1`. It obtains the number of elements, `a` has.

---

Result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char a[1001];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Please enter an integral number up to 1000: ");
    fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
    // scanf("%1000s", a);         Alternative to previous fgets.

    while (a[i] != 0) {
        printf("%c\n", a[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you very much. A few things were incomplete or misspelled in the prev. version. Corrected that in another edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s",&a);
```

Should change to:

```
scanf("%999s",a);
```

or you can use `fgets` from `stdin` instead:

```
fgets(a, 1000, stdin);
```

see [Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the size of the array is too small, it can only contain up to 999 digits.
- the `scanf()` format should specify the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array to avoid undefined behavior on overlong input.
- the `scanf()` argument `&a` is incorrect, it should be just `a`.
- the return value of `scanf()` should be tested to avoid undefined behavior on an empty input file.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[1002]; /* sign + 1000 digits + null terminator */
    if (scanf("%1001s", a) == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            printf("%c\n", a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("error: no input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ma'am,
String in c always end with a null character i.e, '\0' not just 0.
replace this "while(a[i]!=0)" with "while(a[i]!='\0')"..
and everything ll be cool..:-)

Comment: `'\0'` and `0` are 100% absolutely fully unequivocally **absolutely identical** in C.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this?...while(a[i]!=0) and while(a[i]!='\0') are both of these means the same thing?

Comment: Yes, in C source text `0` has value zero and type `int`... `'\0'` has value zero and type `int`. For example: `while (*p != 0)`is 100% identical to `while (*p != '\0')` or `for(j=0;j<9;j++)` is 100% identical to `for(j='\0';j<9;j++)` ...

Comment: also, in C, `sizeof '\0'`, `sizeof 0`, and `sizeof (int)` all have the same value (probably `4`)

Answer (score -1):

Going by your requirement, scanf will take 'a' not '&a'. Also the loop will continue till the end, which is denoted by '\0' character and not zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a[1000];
    int i=0;
    scanf("%s", a);
    while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c\n",a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'\0'` and `0` are the same thing.

Comment: `'\0'` and `0` are 100% absolutely fully unequivocally **absolutely identical** in C.

Comment: @pmg  This amount of adjectives is almost sufficient ^^